# REACTJS: How do I have multiple users on a web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, enums, react-router

I am trying to figure out how to have three users access the web application that I have created. I would like for there to be an admin user, student user, and a public user. Each user has a different set of pages within their navigation bar. I have already been able to set up navigation for a student user and a public user but I am struggling to figure out how to add an admin user and configure the specific pages in the navigation bar for the admin user as well. Here is the following code:

**App.js:**

```
 
{/* using authcontext from the context api */}
export const authContext = createContext();

{/* hold the object for the authentication value */}
function ProvideAuth({ children, auth, setisAuth }) {
  const authValue = {
    auth,
    setisAuth
  };
  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={authValue}> {/* calling value from context api */}
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App() {
  let isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isauthenticated');

  {/* setting the state of isauth to the variable isLoggedin */}
  const [isAuth,setisAuth] = useState(isLoggedIn); 
  // const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isauthenticated');

  // let isLoggedIn; 

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isauthenticated');
  // })
  return (
    
<ProvideAuth auth={isAuth} setisAuth={setisAuth}>
    <Router> 
    <Navbar />  
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/> 
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
      {/* { isLoggedIn != "true" ? (<Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>) : <></> } */}
      <Route path="/sign-up" exact component={SignUp}/> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/virtual-trip" exact component={VirtualTrip} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/step1" exact component={Step1} isAuth={isAuth}/> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/step2" exact component={Step2} isAuth={isAuth} /> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/step3" exact component={Step3} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/step4" exact component={Step4} isAuth={isAuth}/> 
      {/* <PrivateRoute path="/busconvo" exact component={BusConversation} isAuth={isAuth}/> */}
      <PrivateRoute path="/complete" exact component={CompleteTrip} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/> 
      <Route path="/resources" exact component={Resources} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/forgotPassword" exact component={ForgotPassword}/> 
      {/* <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} /> */}
      <Route path="/resources" exact component={Resources}/> 
      <Route path="/about-me" exact component={AboutMe}/> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/scheduler" exact component={Scheduler} isAuth={isAuth}/> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/profile" exact component={Profile} isAuth={isAuth}/> 
      <Route path="/recruitment" exact component={Recruitment}/> 
      <Route path="/field-school" exact component={FieldSchool}/> 
      <Route path="/Home2" exact component={Home2}/> 
      <Route path="/video1" exact component={Video1} isAuth={isAuth} />
      <Route path="/video2" exact component={Video2} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video3" exact component={Video3} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video4" exact component={Video4} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video5" exact component={Video5} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video6" exact component={Video6} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video7" exact component={Video7} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video8" exact component={Video8} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/video9" exact component={Video9} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/taxiconvo" exact component={TaxiConversation} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/busconvo2" exact component={BusConvo2} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/student-scheduler" exact component={StudentScheduler} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/busconvo2spanish" exact component={BusConvo2Spanish} isAuth={isAuth}/>
      <Route path="/taxiconvospanish" exact component={TaxiConversationSpanish} isAuth={isAuth}/>


      <Route path="/resetPassword/:email/:token" exact component={ResetPassword}/> 
      <PrivateRoute path="/logout" exact component={Logout}/> 
      {/* <Route path="/Video" exact component={Video}/> */}
      {/* { isLoggedIn == "true" ? (<PrivateRoute path="/virtual-trip" exact component={VirtualTrip}/>) : <></> } */}

     <Route path="/resetPassword/:email/:token" exact component={ResetPassword}/> 
    </Switch>
    </Router>
</ProvideAuth> 
  );

  
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
const login = () => {
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: loginUsername,
                password: loginPassword,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:4000/login",
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setError(res.data);
            //Redirecting to home after successful authentication
            if(res.data === "Successfully authenticated!"){
                {/* setting the local storage item to true */}
                localStorage.setItem('isauthenticated', true); 
                {/* changing the global state to true as well */}
                auth.setisAuth(true); 
                history.push("/");
                // window.location.reload(false);
            }
        });
    };
```

**Logout.js**

```
const logout = () => {
        {/* removing the item from local storage */}
        localStorage.removeItem('isauthenticated');
        {/* setting global state to false because you're logged out */}
        auth.setisAuth(false); 
        history.push("/");
        // window.location.reload(false);
    }
```

**Navigation.js**

```
 <nav className="navbar"> 
        
            <div className = "navbar-container">
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}> 
                  WAYNE STATE UNIVERSITY  
                </Link>
                <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}> 
                <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} /> 
                </div> 
               <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}> 

                <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/recruitment' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        About 
                    </Link>
                </li> 

                 <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/contact' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Contact   
                    </Link>
                </li>  
                
                { !auth.auth ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/sign-up' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Sign-Up   
                    </Link>
                </li> ) : <></> }

                { !auth.auth  ? (  <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/login' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu} >
                        Login   
                    </Link>
                    </li> ) : <></>}
     
                { auth.auth ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/virtual-trip' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Virtual Trip
                    </Link>
                </li>  ) : <></> }

                { auth.auth ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/resources' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Resources
                    </Link>
                </li>  ) : <></> }
                
                { auth.auth ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/scheduler' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Scheduler
                    </Link>
                </li>  ) : <></> }
                
                <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/about-me' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        About Director 
                    </Link>
                </li> 

                { auth.auth ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={logout}>
                    Logout  
                </Link>
                </li> ) : <></> }

                { auth.auth  ? ( <li className='nav-item'> 
                    <Link to='/profile' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                    <i className="fas fa-user"></i>  
                    </Link>
                </li>  ) : <></> }

                
              </ul> 
            </div> 
            
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of database to store a user? If so you can check for role after login an then display the content for admin, user, whatever ... This can be done by conditional logic eg.

```
user === 'admin' ? <p>Admin page</p> : <p>Student page</p>
```